# Getting an error that the module backports.lzma is not present in the file it should be, but the module installed in my machine. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

The error I am getting is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sweetsourcod.zipper_compress import get_comp_size_bytes
  File "/Users/danielribeiro/Python/sweetsourcod-master/sweetsourcod/zipper_compress.py", line 8, in <module>
    from backports import lzma
ImportError: No module named backports
```

However when I try to install backports.lzma via

```
$ pip install backports.lzma
```

I get the following message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: backports.lzma in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.0.14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
import lzma
```

Check the Usage section of the backports.lzma for more information:
https://pypi.org/project/backports.lzma/